# Error in Databindings in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

so i plan to create a phone book when i double click the data/cell in the datagridview there will be a second form(details form) that will show all the other details of that id and the data should be appear in the textbox  but it doesnt work . so here is my code. thank you!.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    int id;
    id = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    Details details = new Details(id);
    details.Show();

}
```

in details page

```
public Details(int id)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  int val = id;
  GetRecords(val);
}

private void GetRecords(int n) 
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
  int id = n;
  cmd.Connection = cn;
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID ='" + id + "';";

  da = new SqlDataAdapter();
  da.SelectCommand = cmd;

  ds = new DataSet();
  da.Fill(ds, "Employee");
}

private void AddDataBinding()
{
  txtLN.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.LastName");
  txtFN.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.FirstName");
  txtMN.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.MiddleName");
  txtAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.Address");
  txtAge.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.Age");
  txtLN.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.LastName");
  txtPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.Phone");
  txtMobile.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.Mobile");
  txtEmail.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.Email");
  dtBirthday.DataBindings.Add("Value", ds, "Employee.Birthday");
  cbType.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", ds, "Employee.Type");
  txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.OtherName");
  txtOPhone.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.OtherPhone");
  txtOMobile.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Employee.OtherMobile");
}
```

Comment: You never call `AddDataBinding`.  Better learn to use parameters in your sql queries to avoid sql injection.

Comment: **-** In your `CellContentDoubleClick` you are passing `RowIndex` instead of `Id`. **-**  In your detail form you didn't call `AddDataBinding` **-** Consider using parametrized queries. **-** Consider using designer to perform such databinding

Comment: what is the correct syntax to pass the selected employee id? thank you

Comment: @elowearth Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You should find id instead of row index. You should know which column index is for id, for example if your id is in first column, you can use this:

```
var id = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
```

2- Consider using parametrized queries like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID =@Id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id);
//cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
```

3- Perform databinding the way that [Ivan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33176629/3110834) said and call `AddDataBinding`

```
DataTable dt;

private void GetRecords(int n) 
{
    //...
    da.Fill(ds, "Employee");
    dt = ds.Tables["Employee"];
    AddDataBinding();
}

private void AddDataBinding()
{
    txtLN.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "LastName");
    txtFN.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "FirstName");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: how about if the user selected a random row? how can i get the primary key(id) of that selected row?

Comment: @elowearth As I said, you can use `var id = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;` and instead of 0, use index of your `Id` column. Pay attention to `e.RowIndex` that points to the row that user has double clicked on it. You should put that code in `dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick` that you wrote.

Comment: @elowearth By the way, here in StackOverFlow, when you find an answer helpful, you can kindly click on checkmark near the answer to make it accepted. this way it will be more useful for other users. You can accept only one answer but when you gain reputation, you can vote up as many answer as you find helpful including the accepted one, by click on up arrow near the answer.

Comment: `int n;
            n = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            var id = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[n].Value;
            Details details = new Details(id);
            details.Show();}` so i used this code but there is an error "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: @elowearth using `n` in `(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[n].Value;` is wring, you should look at your datagridview and instead of n, use index of the column containing Id :)  This way that you are using n, for row 0 => `(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;` for row 1 => `(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;` for row 2 => `(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;` and ... while it should be for example if id s in your first column  `(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;`

Answer (score 1):

First, the following code `id = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;` smells, make sure you really are getting the emplyeee Id value.

Second, WinForms data bindings do not support "path" (like "Employee.LastName") as WPF do. In order to achieve your goal, you need to bind to `DataTable` instead, like this:

```
DataTable dt;

private void GetRecords(int n) 
{
    //...
    da.Fill(ds, "Employee");
    dt = ds.Tables["Employee"];
}

private void AddDataBinding()
{
    txtLN.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "LastName");
    txtFN.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "FirstName");
    // ...
}
```